# Creating a for loop with inputs in Java

Tags: java, image, loops, for-loop, pixel

Here is my code:

```
 public static Picture modifyPicture (Picture p, int value)
 {
  // get width and height of the picture
  int width = p.getWidth();
  int height = p.getHeight();
  System.out.println ("Picture has width of " + width + 
                      " and height of " + height);

  Picture p2 = new Picture (width, height*value);

  int x = -1;
  int y = -1;

  for  ( x = 0 ; x < width ;  ++x )
  {
    for ( y = 0 ; y < height ; ++y )
    {
     Pixel pixel1 = p.getPixel (x,y);
     Color c1 = pixel1.getColor();

     Pixel pixel4 = p2.getPixel (x, y);
     pixel4.setColor( c1 );

     Pixel pixel5 = p2.getPixel (x, y + 1 * height);
     pixel5.setColor( c1 );

     Pixel pixel6 = p2.getPixel (x, y + 2 * height);
     pixel6.setColor( c1 );
   }
 }
 return p2; 
}  // end of method
```

Hey guys, this seems like a simple problem but I cannot figure out how I could do this. I want to somehow loop the items inside of the for loop. What the code does is places pictures vertically on top of each other. This code works for 3 pictures (value = 3), but if I wanted less or more pictures, I have to keep adding/removing a new line i.e. Pixel pixel7 etc.

I need a way to loop this according to the number in value. I'm not looking for you to write my code for me, just give me some idea how I could do this. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: for(int z = 0; z < value; z++) { ... } ???

Comment: I will try that I was actually thinking about another nested loop just didn't get the results I wanted. I will let you know if this worked, thanks!

Comment: This worked, thank you! I was just over-complicating the innards of the actual looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your method to loop `value` times for each pixel:

```
public static Picture modifyPicture (Picture p, int value)
 {
  // get width and height of the picture
  int width = p.getWidth();
  int height = p.getHeight();
  System.out.println ("Picture has width of " + width + 
                      " and height of " + height);    
  Picture p2 = new Picture (width, height*value);

  for  (int x = 0 ; x < width ;  ++x )
  {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; ++y )
    {
     Pixel pixel1 = p.getPixel (x,y);
     Color c1 = pixel1.getColor();

     for (int j=1; j < value; j++) {
          Pixel pixel = p2.getPixel (x, y + j * height);
          pixel.setColor( c1 );
     }
   }
 }
 return p2; 
}  // end of method
```

Comment: Yup, this worked. I was over-complicating it by thinking I had to set a new pixel every time, Thank you very much for your time and the answer!